# Trouble with Functions in basic Javascript menu program

Tags: javascript

For my Intro to Comp Sci course, the professor is asking us to implement functions into one main function for an assignment that we've already completed with do-while and for loops, switch statements, and basic conditional programming. However, he did not instruct us well on how to accomplish this.

This is how the code from the original assignment looks like without functions.

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
    var menu_choice;

    do {
      menu_choice = 1 * prompt("-----Menu------\n\n" +
        "1. Addition\n" +
        "2. Multiplication\n" +
        "3. Expenentiation\n" +
        "4. String Concatenation\n" +
        "5. Logical AND (&&)\n" +
        "6. Logical OR (||)\n" +
        "7. Quit\n\n" +
        "Enter your choice (1-7):");
      switch (menu_choice) {
        case 1:
          var iterations = 1*prompt("Enter number of numbers to add");
          var sum = 1*prompt("Enter a number:");
          for(var i = 1;i < iterations; i++){
          sum += 1*prompt("Enter a number:");}
          alert("The sum is " + sum);
          document.write("The sum is " + sum + "<br><br>");
          break;

        case 2:
          var iterations = 1*prompt("Enter number of numbers to multiply");
          var product = 1;
          for(var i = 1;i <= iterations; i++){
          product *= 1*prompt("Enter a number:");}
          alert("The product is " + product);
          document.write("The product is " + product + "<br><br>");
          break;

        case 3:
          var iterations = 1*prompt("Enter number of numbers to exponentiate");
          var result = 1*prompt("Enter a number");
          for(var i = 1;i < iterations; i++){
          result = Math.pow(result, 1*prompt("Enter a number"));}
          alert("The exponentiation is " + result);
          document.write("The exponentiation is " + result + "<br><br>");
          break;

        case 4:
          var iterations = 1*prompt("Enter the number of strings to concatenate:");
          var result = prompt("Enter a string");
          for(var i = 1;i < iterations; i++){
          result += prompt("Enter a string");}
          alert("The concatenated string is " + result);
          document.write("The concatenated string is " + result + "<br><br>");
          break;

        case 5:
          var iterations = 1*prompt("Enter the number of booleans to AND:");
          var string = prompt("Enter a boolean (true or false):").toLowerCase();
          var result = string;  
          if (result === "true")
              var result = true;
          else 
              var result = false;  
          for (var i = 1; i < iterations; i++){
          var string = prompt("Enter a boolean (true or false):").toLowerCase();
          var newbool = string;
          if (newbool === "true")
            var newbool = true;
          else 
            var newbool = false;
          var result = (result && newbool)
          }
          alert("The ANDing of the booleans is: " + result);
          document.write("The ANDing of the booleans is: " + result + "<br><br>");
          break;

        case 6:
          var iterations = 1*prompt("Enter the number of booleans to OR:");
          var string = prompt("Enter a boolean (true or false):").toLowerCase();
          var result = string;  
          if (result === "true")
              var result = true;
          else 
              var result = false;  
          for (var i = 1; i < iterations; i++){
          var string = prompt("Enter a boolean (true or false):").toLowerCase();
          var newbool = string;
          if (newbool === "true")
            var newbool = true;
          else 
            var newbool = false;
          var result = (result || newbool)
          }
          alert("The ORing of the booleans is: " + result);
          document.write("The ORing of the booleans is: " + result + "<br><br>");
          break;

        case 7:
          document.write("Quitting the program...");
          break;

        default:
          document.write("Error: invalid input (must be 1-7)<br><br>");
      }

    }
    while (menu_choice !== 7)
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Right now I'm just trying to work on case 1, but I think I'm getting caught up with writing a function for the '+=' operator. In testing (with JSrunner) I only got the function to work with two numbers.

Here's the code that I've been testing for case 1.

```
var number_of_numbers, final_result;

var iterations = function (op)
{
  return 1*prompt("Enter the number of numbers to " + op + ":");  
};

var input = function()
{
  return 1*prompt("Enter a number:");     
};

var sum_plus = function()
{   
  var result = input();   
  return result += 1*prompt("Enter a number:");
};

number_of_numbers = iterations("add");
for(var i = 1;i < number_of_numbers; i++){
           final_result = sum_plus();};
alert("The sum is " + final_result);
```

Is it possible to put the for loop inside of the sum_plus function? Or is it better calling the function inside the for loop?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important that you know what your code is doing. To answer your question, the only code we really need to look at is the `sum_plus` function

```
var sum_plus = function() {
  var result = input();   
  return result += 1*prompt("Enter a number:");
};
```

And the code to run it:

```
number_of_numbers = iterations("add");
for(var i = 1;i < number_of_numbers; i++) {
  final_result = sum_plus();
}

alert("The sum is " + final_result);
```

Right now this code will, for each iteration, call `sum_plus()`. `sum_plus()` will:

1) Ask the user for a number and store it in the variable `result`

```
var result = input();
```

2) Ask the user for another number, multiply it by 1, add it to the variable `result` and return it.

```
return result += 1*prompt("Enter a number:");
```

So, for each time the `for` loop runs, your code will take two numbers, add them, and store them in `final_result`, then at the end will alert the sum of the last two numbers entered.

It sounds like what you want your code to do, is take `input()` store it in `result` then run a loop that takes a new input value and adds it to `result`.

Your `sum_plus` function should look something like this:

```
var sum_plus = function(iteration_count) {
  // Take an input and store it in the variable `result`
  var result = input();

  // Run a loop `iteration_count` times
  for (var i = 0; i < iteration_count; i++) {
    // Every time the loop runs, take an input and add it to result
    result += input(); // This is the same as `result = result + input();
  }
  // Return the value
  return result;
}
```

Now you can call the function with:

```
alert(sum_plus(iterations("add")));
```

Or the longer version which is almost exactly the same thing:

```
var iterations = iterations("add");
var sum = sum_plus(iterations);
alert(sum);
```

***Make sure you really understand how this works, don't just copy my code. Functions and loops are the building blocks of modern code. Without them you won't get anywhere. If you have any questions about what's happening, feel free to ask.***

Help with functions: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Help with `for` loops: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking to do. I'm trying to think of a solution based on what you told me, but unfortunately I can't come up with anything. I've been working on this for hours because our teacher barely went over functions and haphazardly went over looping, so I've had to kind of teach myself. I'm thinking it might have to do with the syntax of the sum_plus function and not the for loop but I'm not totally sure.

Comment: @MaxSilbert Think you could bang an up-vote on there too? :)

Comment: Thank you so very much! I won't just copy the code and move on, I'm definitely going to go over those pages you provided. I guess I just needed to look at the solution and then analyze the code over in order to learn it (because I never got proper lessons). Thanks again, I'm going to work on the other cases in the menu now.

Comment: I'm sorry I tried to upvote it but I don't have enough reputation points. Once I get enough though, I'll come back and upvote the crap out of it! :) Thanks again.